# How to remove rows that represent permutation of other's in a given matrix

Tags: r

Assume we have some matrix `r` such that :

```
    m=structure(c(1, 0.996805114543033, 0.987281571590291, 0.971610767189123, 
    0.950088633802627, 0.996805114543033, 0.993620436379149, 0.984127320055285, 
    0.996805114543033, 1, 0.996805114543033, 0.987281571590291, 0.971610767189123, 
    0.993620436379149, 0.996805114543033, 0.993620436379149, 0.987281571590291, 
    0.996805114543033, 1, 0.996805114543033, 0.987281571590291, 0.984127320055285, 
    0.993620436379149, 0.996805114543033, 0.971610767189123, 0.987281571590291, 
    0.996805114543033, 1, 0.996805114543033, 0.968506582079198, 0.984127320055285, 
    0.993620436379149, 0.950088633802627, 0.971610767189123, 0.987281571590291, 
    0.996805114543033, 1, 0.947053209443661, 0.968506582079198, 0.984127320055285, 
    0.996805114543033, 0.993620436379149, 0.984127320055285, 0.968506582079198, 
    0.947053209443661, 1, 0.996805114543033, 0.987281571590291, 0.993620436379149, 
    0.996805114543033, 0.993620436379149, 0.984127320055285, 0.968506582079198, 
    0.996805114543033, 1, 0.996805114543033, 0.984127320055285, 0.993620436379149, 
    0.996805114543033, 0.993620436379149, 0.984127320055285, 0.987281571590291, 
    0.996805114543033, 1), .Dim = c(8L, 8L))
    
    k=5
    
    inds <- which(`dim<-`(m %in% head(sort(c(m)), k), dim(m)), arr.ind = TRUE)
    
    r=inds[order(m[inds]), ]
    
    print(r)
    
          row col
    [1,]   6   5
    [2,]   5   6
    [3,]   5   1
    [4,]   1   5
    [5,]   6   4
    [6,]   7   5
    [7,]   4   6
    [8,]   5   7
    
    dput(r)

    structure(c(6L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 
    5L, 6L, 7L), .Dim = c(8L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("row", 
    "col")))
```

I'm searching to drop duplicated rows of the `r` matrix. The duplicated rows in this context are rows that represent a permutation of other's. For example : `row1=c(6,5) & row2=c(5,6)` are duplicated => so I need to remove one of them.

Thank you for help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can loop over the rows with `apply` (`MARGIN = 1`), `sort` the elements, get the `t`ranspose, then use `duplicated` on those data to remove the duplicate elements from r

```
r1 <- r[!duplicated(t(apply(r, 1, sort))),]
```

-output

```
r1
#     row col
#[1,]   6   5
#[2,]   5   1
#[3,]   6   4
#[4,]   7   5
```

---

Or using `pmin/pmax` in a vectorized way

```
r[!duplicated(cbind(pmin(r[,1], r[,2]), pmax(r[,1], r[,2]))),]
```

Comment: Thank  you @akrun . I didn't understand the second solution. `pmin/pmax` will work for matrices with a number of columns greater than 2 ?

Comment: @TouMou For that you may need some changes in the code ie. `do.call` and convert to data.frame

Answer (score 3):

Here is one option using `igraph` package

```
r %>%
  graph_from_data_frame(directed = FALSE) %>%
  simplify() %>%
  get.data.frame()
```

which gives

```
  from to
1    6  5
2    6  4
3    5  1
4    5  7
```